# Unable to bulk insert from flat file in SQL

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, flat-file

If I execute the script below, the data can be inserted into the table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.loadDataFrFlatFile

AS
BEGIN


BULK INSERT PERSONS
FROM 'C:\SampleData1.csv'
WITH (FieldTerminator = '|', RowTerminator = '\n')
END

RETURN 1

GO

EXEC dbo.loadDataFrFlatFile
```

However, if I put the file path as an input variable, it doesn't work.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.loadDataFrFlatFile
(
    @flatFilePath varchar(255)
)

AS
BEGIN    

BULK INSERT PERSONS
FROM ' + @flatFilePath + '
WITH (FieldTerminator = '|', RowTerminator = '\n')
END

RETURN 1

GO

EXEC dbo.loadDataFrFlatFile @flatFilePath = 'C:\SampleData1.csv'
```

The error shown is:

```
Msg 4860, Level 16, State 1, Procedure loadDataFrFlatFile, Line 12
Cannot bulk load. The file " + @flatFilePath + " does not exist.
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use dynamic sql for that, e.g.:

```
create procedure dbo.loadDataFrFlatFile ( @flatFilePath varchar(255) ) as
begin;
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'bulk insert persons
from ''' + @flatFilePath + '''
with (FieldTerminator = ''|'', RowTerminator = ''\n'')
';
exec sp_executesql @sql;
return 1
end;
go

exec dbo.loadDataFrFlatFile @flatFilePath = 'C:\SampleData1.csv'
```

Be careful with this regarding sql injection, make sure only those who need to use it have the permission to execute it.

You can also white-list and blacklist the values the variable can contain prior to concatenating and executing it.

dynamic sql reference:

- [The curse and blessings of dynamic SQL - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)
- [**`sp_executesql`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql

try something like

```
DECLARE @bulk_cmd varchar(1000);  
SET @bulk_cmd = 'BULK INSERT AdventureWorks2012.Sales.SalesOrderDetail  
FROM ''<drive>:\<path>\<filename>''   
WITH (ROWTERMINATOR = '''+CHAR(10)+''')';  
EXEC(@bulk_cmd);
```